# How can I delete data is checked in checkbox?

Tags: python, django

I want to delete data is checked in checkbox.I wrote in html

```
<div id="now">
　<form  action="/app/delete" method="POST">
    {% for item in data %}
        <div class="left">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
                <p>{{ item.email }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
　</form>
</div>
```

in views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def done(request):
    delete_ids = request.POST.getlist('delete_ids')
　　 print(delete_ids)
    if delete_ids:
        Data.objects.filter(id__in=delete_ids).delete()

    return render(request, 'top.html')
```

My ideal system is when I check checkbox of items and put SUBMIT button, done method is called, and checked data is deleted.But when I check checkbox and put SUBMIT button, nothing happens.print(delete_ids) shows empty list like [],so I think checked data cannot be gotten.How can I send checked data to Django?What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: I mean as written, you're using what a checkbox does backwards.   If unchecked it sends nothing, and if checked it passes value \ "on".  It would be easier to hold the "value" in a hidden input and toggle it with an onclick function than try to remap how a checkbox works.

Answer (score 0):

agree with @MasonStedman 
you should do soemthing like this something like

```
<div class="left">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
                <p>{{ item.email }}</p>
<input type="hidden" name="delete_ids[]" value="{{item.id}}" />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.I have a question, how can I connect input button & done method?

Comment: you can connect it using ajax..you will pass the done method inside ajax and all the data and it will call your method asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

If I have checkbox defined like below:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
```

I can use javascript

```
 <script>

    var isChecked
    isChecked = document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked;
    checkbox_status= isChecked.toString()    
    return alert_status;

 </script>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.I have a question, how can I connect input button & done method?

Comment: Use jquery to send post request on that url

Comment: Refer post method in the following link which exactly send status of the check box to the post method in django views.py. https://github.com/prasad01dalavi/security_serveillance/blob/master/Server/security_serveillance/templates/video_response.html